# HP DL160 G6 memory PC3-10600R vs PC3-10600E

Tags: memory, hp, hp-proliant

I am using a HP DL 160 G6 server that according to [specs](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/13247_na/13247_na.html) takes PC3 Registered or Unbuffered.  When I combine the two types of memory below the system will not POST.  When I use just the first type of memory listed the system will POST.

I have two pieces of HP memory that came with the server labeled

```
PC3-10600E-9-10-E0
```

and then I have some Crucial memory labeled

```
PC3-10600R-9-10-B0
```

I wager that the R means Registered memory and the E means ECC - then shouldn't the crucial memory boot with the system according to the HP specs? Or does the E mean it is Unbuffered and therefore I shouldn't mix and match as according to [this HP memory config doc](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/13344_na/13344_na.HTML#Memory)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference between the RAM modules you have is UDIMM (unbuffered) versus RDIMM memory; unregistered versus registered. They cannot be mixed in the same server. So you are correct, the memory guide states not to mix the two.
http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/13344_na/13344_na.HTML#Memory

`Do not mix Unbuffered memory (UDIMMs) with Registered memory (RDIMMs).`

Comment: That is what I was beginning to suspect.  My next question is that since the Crucial memory is labeled E for ECC does it stand to reason that ECC and Non-ECC fall into the Unbuffered category?

Comment: UDIMMs can be ECC. There are just greater restrictions on them with Nehalem-based systems. I have plenty of servers using the UDIMMs that come standard on the HP 100-series servers. You're just limited to population of 2 slots per DIMM bank and a total of 12GB ram on the server you're dealing with.

Comment: Can an RDIMM work in Ubuffered system