# Is more memory better, or more DIMMs

Tags: windows, 64-bit

Dell PowerEdge T610, came with 4x 2GB UDIMMs. I replaced those with 2x 8GB RDIMMs. Filled the empty slots with blanks. I just want to make sure that I'm not hurting performance by replacing all 4. I do realize 4x 8GB RDIMMs would be better than 2.

Comment: You want to us to tell you if your computer is now going faster? Don't you know?

Comment: In general 4x2GB MAY be faster then 2x4GB, but 2x8GB is double the RAM you had previously, and therefore will improve performance by a lot.

Comment: If you're wondering why this question is a dupe of the one listed, have a look at Steve Lippert's answer: http://serverfault.com/a/289102/7709

Answer (score 0):

I think you're gonna have to find a benchmark that works for you, and then try it in some different memory configurations to really have any clue which is "faster" or "better"

Comment: Server has been running fine, then it slowed down a few days ago. It serves 3-4 4D databases. Ran diags and everything checks out. I then swapped from the UDIMMs to the RDIMMs. Not much improvement, so just trying to isolate whether adding more RDIMMs may be the solution. Thanks for the comments.