# How do I upgrade my HP ProLiant ML150 G6 server RAM?

Tags: memory, hardware, hp, hp-proliant

I want to upgrade the RAM on two HP ProLiant ML150 G6. They currently have 2 dimms labeled 2GB 2RX8 PC3-10600E-9-10-E0. I believe these are UDIMMs? The servers have a total of 12 memory slots.

In each server dimms populate two contiguous slots in one of the two 6-slot sets on the motherboard.

I have read another article: [HP DL160 G6 memory PC3-10600R vs PC3-10600E](https://serverfault.com/questions/222207/hp-dl160-g6-memory-pc3-10600r-vs-pc3-10600e) and also some documentation from HP website, but I don´t know if our servers will handle 24GB each (12 2GB dimms). I am posting this question before purchasing any dimms.

Enrique S.

Comment: Does this help: http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/servers/options/tool/hp_memtool.html

Answer (score 2):

You currently have UDIMM unbuffered RAM.

Your server can accommodate two CPUs. There are TWELVE DIMM slots, but only SIX of them are available if you have one CPU. Since your existing RAM is in two adjacent slots, you probably have a single CPU installed. You can use the six slots associated with that CPU for RAM.

The [memory guide within the Quickspecs](http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/13249_div/13249_div.html#Memory) for the HP ProLiant ML150 G6 outline your RAM options.

The [Memory Configuration Tool](http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/servers/options/tool/hp_memtool.html) linked above will give you the specifics and part numbers needed to make this happen. Ideally, you'll want to use all registered RAM (fewer constraints). Look for HP part #500658-B21 for 4GB DIMMS.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Yes I have a single CPU installed.
I was told by a salesperson that I won´t be able to use 4GB modules unless they are registered. That unbuffered DIMM max size would be 2GB. What do you think?

Comment: Use registered RAM anyway. The unbuffered DIMMs have too many downsides to be considered useful in your scenario. When I encounter systems that have unbuffered RAM, I discard it and replace with registered when I need to add more RAM. The [link I provided in the answer](http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/13249_div/13249_div.html#Memory) lays out all of the RAM combinations and the part numbers for registered and unbuffered DIMMs. ***UDIMM Maximum Configuration (1 CPU model) via 6 x 4GB UDIMMs*** - 4GB UDIMM (HP [#500672-B21](http://h30094.www3.hp.com/product/sku/10238522))

Answer (score 0):

[Your server will handle up to 48 GB RAM](http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/ds_00148/ds_00148.pdf) (12x4GB DIMMs), and takes DDR3, 1066 MHz Unbuffered **or** Registered RAM. (Don't mix and match - either all registered or all unbuffered DIMMs).

So, provided you purchase the correct RAM type and all are either Registered or Unbuffered, it will accommodate 24 GB in 12 2GB DIMMs.  6x4GB DIMMs would also work, and may be cheaper, FYI.

Be aware, however, that each bank of RAM slots is assigned to a processor, so to actually utilize all 12 slots requires having both processor sockets populated.  If you just have one processor, you'll want to buy 6x4GB DIMMs and place them in the bank of slots corresponding to the populated processor socket.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Yes I have a single CPU installed.
I was told by a salesperson that I won´t be able to use 4GB modules unless they are registered. That unbuffered DIMM max size would be 2GB. What do you think?

Comment: @EnriqueSoto The salesman is wrong, but you want to use registered RAM anyway, as ewwhite said.  [Here's a little link on the difference between the two](http://www.servethehome.com/unbuffered-registered-ecc-memory-difference-ecc-udimms-rdimms/) - summary version is that Unbuffered is the cheap stuff, while Registered allows more reliability, better error correction and higher memory bandwidth.